# AWS Node install Error: npm WARN enoent ENOENT, open '/home/ec2-user/examplefolder/package.json'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

New to node. New to AWS. First time setup. Pretty straight forward install on AWS. This is the error message received. Is this something I should worry about or just not?  thanks.

```
npm install utils aws-sdk async gm path

npm WARN enoent ENOENT, open '/home/ec2-user/examplefolde/package.json'
npm WARN examplefolder No description
npm WARN examplefolder No repository field.
npm WARN examplefolder No README data
npm WARN examplefolder No license field.
```

Comment: IT is a WARN so i wouldn't worry much about it, but you need to understand why you getting them! try read about npm and npm packages and how they are structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a check as of NPM, they report this as a warning.

However, don't worry, there are *sooooooo* many packages which still don't have the `repository` field in their `package.json`.  The field is used for informational purposes.

In the case you're a package author, put the `repository` in your `package.json`, like this:

```
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git://github.com/username/repository.git"
}
```

Read more about the [`repository`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository) field, and see the [logged bug](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3568) for further details.

---

You can set `private` key in your `package.json`.
This will not only stop you from accidentally running `npm publish` in your app, but will also stop NPM from printing warnings regarding `package.json` problems.

```
{
  "name": "my-super-amazing-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.